# Rails 3 Model Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a company

The company can have one status

I am getting myself confused in how to set-up my associations in the models

Basically in the views, i will have a drop down of the statuses and the user selects one for each company...

```
companies
id
name
status_id

company_statuses 
id
status (Unknown, Live, Dissolved, etc...)
```

My way of thinking for using a company_statuses table is that they could change overtime and simply changing the name of the status in the table updates all companies at once etc...

Is this the rails way ?!, or would i be better hardcoding the values in the code and updating the database manually if changes need to be made ?!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working by using the following code. It is a has_many relationship not has_one

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status_code
end

class StatusCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A company has one status right? If this is the case, the relationship is many to one and does not require a company_status link table. Simply configure your company table to have a status column.

My Rails 3 is a little rusty but your company model will feature:

```
has_one :status
```

And your Status model will have:

```
belongs_to :company
```

Comment: I am a little confused still, you have a has_one association above but you say the relationship is many to one ? Also I need a table to hold the statuses in the database (company_statuses). Status is too generic because of the other tables i have...

Comment: Yep, has_one is there as a Company "has one" status. Conversely, a Status "belongs_to" a company (thanks Ryan for the edit!). You can still have a table for Status which consists of a unique ID and the status name. Your Company table will contain a status foreign key (status_fk). Note that you shouldn't have to worry about creating this key yourself, Rails should look after this for you once you've your relationships correctly set.

Comment: Really confused now lol... According to the docs "belongs_to" Specifies a one-to-one association with another class. This method should only be used if this class contains the foreign key.If the other class contains the foreign key, then you should use "has_one" instead... It should be the other way around I think!??

Comment: Hmmm i still think the associations are wrong on this setup because of the "belongs_to" on the StatusCode model. It is expecting a company_id in the stautus_codes table.. 

For example if I declare a company object and call status_code on it 

    testcompany.status_code 

its trying to run the following sql 

    SELECT * FROM status_codes WHERE status_codes.company_id = 2 LIMIT 1

Is there no way to tell rails that the foreign key(status_code_id) column is in the companies table !?!?

    COMPANIES
    id
    name
    status_code_id

    STATUS_CODES
    id
    name